# TableModelListener event from keyboard

Tags: java, swing, events, keyboard, jtable

I Have a Jtable where a TableModelListener is listening

Implemented by

```
private void anadeListenerAlModelo() {
    tabla.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
        @Override
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent evento) {
            if (evento.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE) {
                System.out.println("Editing...");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And I want to detect when a cell is being edit but only if is edit from de keyboard, because, other events could update the content.

I only need when the user is editing a cell from the keyboard. It's this posible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Table Cell Listener](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/).

It listens for PropertyChange events on the table for when the cell editor is activated/deactivated and then notifies you when the data in the cell has actually been changed.